# ContextMenu for a disabled Button

Tags: c#, contextmenu

I want to make a contextmenu, that is shown when the user makes a "Right-Click" onto the contorol, which is a button. Unfortunately some of the buttons are disabled. Can someone help me and told me how to give them also a contextmenu?

My (not working) try:

```
        private void ShowRightClickMenu(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenu Temp = new ContextMenu();
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && secondTagObj[Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).Tag)].typ != string.Empty)
        {
            this.ContextMenu = Temp;        // works
            Temp.MenuItems.Add("Create.."); //works
            Temp.MenuItems.Add("Delete");   // works
        }
        if (raster[Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).Tag)].Enabled == false && e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            this.ContextMenu = Temp;        // works not
            Temp.MenuItems.Add("New...");   // works not
        }
        else
        {
            this.ContextMenu = Temp;        // works, but only if button is visible
            Temp.MenuItems.Add("New...");   // works, but only if button is visible
        }
    }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you can use the `ContextMenuService` to enable the contextmenu for disabled controls.

```
private void ShowRightClickMenu(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenu Temp = new ContextMenu();
    ContextMenuService.SetShowOnDisabled((Button)sender, true);
...
```

[Update for better readabiltiy]
For WinForms have a look at [this entry at microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2977f3ae-5522-4ba5-a52e-133feebd51d4/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately its a normal Forms and not a Wpf, so i cant use System.Windows.Controls. But Thanks :)

Comment: hmm that´s too bad, but you could have a look at this link, maybe this helps you out: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2977f3ae-5522-4ba5-a52e-133feebd51d4/)

Answer (score 2):

*(Assuming this question is for WPF, as indicated in the comments of @medasocles answer...)*

To use the `ContextMenuService` as alluded to by @medasocles in WPF, you would do the following:

```xml
<Button Content="Blah" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Context Item" Command="{Binding MyContextCommand}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

I don't believe this will actually solve your problem though. I think it would be easier to put your button in a frame, like a border, and add your context menus to the border. I would then add a trigger to the Button that sets `IsHitTestVisible` to `False` when the button is disabled, thus allowing interactions to pass through to the border behind and your menu to work as expected.

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly :)